# Generalizing Voronoi summation and the inverse Mellin transform of $(2^{1-s} \pi^{-s} \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(s))^n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I'm working through the helpful paper [The Voronoi summation formula](http://www.individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/voronoi.pdf) from Jordan Bell, and I think I'm finally understanding it in broad strokes.

But I'm running into hurdles in my own attempts to use it, owing to some challenging (to me) inverse Mellin transforms.

Essentially, I want to explore Voronoi summation style formulas for more generalized divisor functions.  So, say, $d_3(n) = \sum_{j \cdot k \cdot l = n} 1$, $d_4(n) = \sum_{j \cdot k \cdot l \cdot m = n} 1$, and so on.

In the original Voronoi summation context of $d(n)$, the non-smooth part of the formula for $\sum_{k=1}^y d(k)$ is expressed in terms of the infinite sum $\sum_{k=1}  d(k) \int_{0}^y F_2(k x) \,dx$, where $F_2(x)$ is the inverse Mellin transform of $(2^{1-s} \pi^{-s} \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(s))^2$ at $\Re(s)=3/2$.  The linked paper goes into a much clearer explanation for how this works, but essentially it's the inverse Mellin transform of the non-zeta factors in the reflection formula for $\zeta(s)^2$.  And in this case, it can be written as $4 K_0\left(4 \pi  \sqrt{x}\right)- 2 \pi Y_0\left(4 \pi \sqrt{x}\right)$, where $K_0(x)$ and $Y_0(x)$ are Bessel functions.

If I'm following everything correctly, this means that if I want Voronoi summation style formulas for the non-smooth parts of $\sum_{k=1}^y d_m(k)$ where $m$ is a whole number, I need to evaluate the inverse Mellin transforms of the non-zeta factors of the reflection formula for $\zeta(s)^m$, which is to say, the inverse Mellin transform of $(2^{1-s} \pi^{-s} \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(s))^m$ at $\Re(s)=3/2$.  Call that $F_m(x)$.  Then the non-smooth part of $\sum_{k=1}^y d_m(k)$ should be expressed as $\sum_{k=1}  d_m(k) \int_{0}^y F_m(k x) \,dx$.

If I'm correct in my understanding of everything so far, that still leaves the issue of evaluating those inverse Mellin transforms, which is not obvious to me.

For what it's worth, I tried evaluating them using Mathematica, and it suggested that

$$F_3(x)=2 \pi ^{3/2} G_{0,6}^{3,0}\left(\pi ^3 x,\frac{1}{2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and has similar results for higher values of $m$, all in terms of Meijer-G functions, but when I tried using that in my sum $\sum_{k=1}  d_3(k) \int_{0}^y F_3(k x) \,dx$, it appears to rapidly blow up to infinity.

So that's my question.  Is there a reasonable / natural way to evaluate the inverse Mellin transforms of $(2^{1-s} \pi^{-s} \cos(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(s))^m$ for this context?

Alternatively, are there any references to work that covers these topics?  I've found a number of papers on the original Voronoi summation formula but am having no luck on this extension.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say Mathematica 'suggested' $F_3$ is a Meijer G-function?  What do you mean by 'appears' to blow up at infinity?